# How could we detect if Venus or mars were being terraformed by aliens?

Tags: solar-system, mars, venus, planetary-science

If any other body in our solar system was being terraformed by aliens, what would be the ways in which we would detect this?

Initially I thought of Venus or mars but I guess this could extend to any body within the solar system.

What would be the first signs? Who would be the people that would actually start detecting changes?

Comment: Doesn't this depend very much on exactly how terraforming was being done and at what stage it was currently at? I think this question is way too broad and opinion-based to be a good Astronomy SE question. It's possibly suited to [World Building SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) but even there, you might need to add some more details or be ready to respond to comments *asking for* details.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires too much speculation not based in science - especially not based in Astronomy (so off-topic) and lacks any specifics. There isn't a single, generic "terraforming work flow" or SOP we can work from.

Comment: This question _might_ be appropriate for Space SE as [they do discuss terraforming](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terraforming), albeit usually from the perspective of how we could do it.

Comment: Relevant to planetary atmospheres, spectroscopy, recurring observational programs.

Comment: Perhaps Venus was “terraformed” by aliens who prefer such an atmosphere. Ok, unlikely, but why think aliens would prefer what we do?

Comment: @JonCuster I never said they preferred what we prefer.